# Syntax error in a shortcode function

Tags: php, shortcode, fatal-error

I'm trying to implement a taboola ad unit in a shortcode function, but I'm getting a syntax error. Below is the function that creates the shortcode. The code is in my functions.php file.

Can someone please help me figure out 'why' I'm getting the error and help me correct it?

```
/**
 * in article placement
 */

function contentMid(){
return '<div id="xxxx-xxxxxx"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window._taboola = window._taboola || [];
  _taboola.push({
    mode: 'xxxxxxx-xxxxx',
    container: 'xxxxxx-xxxxxxx',
    placement: 'one word word',
    target_type: 'mix'
  });
</script>';
}
add_shortcode('contentMid', 'contentMid');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes, or use doubles, or use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
// Escaped
return '<div id="xxxx-xxxxxx"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window._taboola = window._taboola || [];
    _taboola.push({
        mode: \'xxxxxxx-xxxxx\',
        container: \'xxxxxx-xxxxxxx\',
        placement: \'one word word\',
        target_type: \'mix\'
    });
</script>';

// Doubles
return '<div id="xxxx-xxxxxx"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window._taboola = window._taboola || [];
    _taboola.push({
        mode: "xxxxxxx-xxxxx",
        container: "xxxxxx-xxxxxxx",
        placement: "one word word",
        target_type: "mix"
    });
</script>';

// Heredoc
return <<<html
<div id="xxxx-xxxxxx"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window._taboola = window._taboola || [];
    _taboola.push({
        mode: "xxxxxxx-xxxxx",
        container: "xxxxxx-xxxxxxx",
        placement: "one word word",
        target_type: "mix"
    });
</script>
html;
```

Comment: Thank your TheDeadMedic for your help and the options you provided. I used the escape method and it worked perfectly!